# Find Fenchel conjugate for a function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, subgradient

During my self learning I come across the function for which I want to find (Fenchel) conjugate and the subdifferential $\partial \psi$ function, could you please help! I have no clue about this topic.

$$\psi (t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac 1 2 t^2& t > 0\\
-t & t \leq 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What has $x$ to do with $t$? Why not just apply the definition?

Comment: @copper.hat It was typo i edited it.

Comment: What is the definition of a Fenchel conjugate?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I found many definition and got confused.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger It is also called the convex conjugate.

Comment: I am curious what other definitions you found, all definitions I found are the same.

Comment: @copper.hat I confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw a little picture of the graph of $\psi$.

$\psi^*(y) = \sup_t yt-\psi(t)$.

From the picture it should be clear that there are three cases 1. $y\ge 0$, 2. $y \in[-1,0)$ and 3. $y<-1$.

Case 1. $y \ge 0$, we see that $\sup_{t < 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t < 0}  (y+1)t = 0$ and
$\sup_{t \ge 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t \ge 0} yt - {1 \over 2} t^2 = {1 \over 2} y^2$ and so $\psi^*(y) = {1 \over 2} y^2$.

Case 2. $y \in[-1,0)$, we see that $\sup_{t < 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t < 0}  (y+1)t = 0$ and
$\sup_{t \ge 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t \ge 0} yt - {1 \over 2} t^2 = 0$ and so $\psi^*(y) = 0$.

Case 3. $y <-1$, we see that $\sup_{t < 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t < 0}  (y+1)t = +\infty$ and
$\sup_{t \ge 0}  yt-\psi(t)= \sup_{t \ge 0} yt - {1 \over 2} t^2 = 0$ and so $\psi^*(y) = +\infty$.

To compute the subgradient, perhaps the most straightforward way is to compute the (one sided) directional derivatives. Then the subgradient is the convex set whose support function is the directional derivative.

If $\psi$ is $C^1$ at $t$ then $d \psi(t,h) = \psi'(t) h$ and so $\partial \psi(t) = \{ \psi'(t) \}$.

We see that $\psi$ is $C^1$ everywhere except at $t=0$, in which case we have $d \psi(0, h) = -h$ for $h <0$ and $d \psi(0,h) = th$ for $h \ge 0$ and so $\partial \psi(0) = [-1,0]$.

Comment: Thanks so much. But why $y \in [-1,0)$ ? in the graph y is never below zero!

Comment: I do not know what you are referring to. What graph y?

Comment: Oh, I confused between $y$ and $\psi$. What is $y$ here. I am just trying to understand the logic behind your steps!

Comment: I think in case 3 you were meaning $y <-1$.

Comment: @SelfLearner Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: $y$ is just the parameter to $\psi^*$, technically an element of $\mathbb{R}^*$.